# Trying to get the mac/hardware address of any android device

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-widget

I am writing code to get the mac address of any Android device having versions greater than 2.3. In general, I wrote the following code in HiActivity.java :

```
package com.hi.address;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HiActivity extends Activity 
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
                
    }
    public void Display()
    {
        try {
    InetAddress addresses = InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());

       NetworkInterface ni= NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(addresses);

       byte[] mac = ni.getHardwareAddress();
       System.out.println("====="+mac); 
       for(int i=0; i< mac.length; i++) 
       {
                 
           System.out.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : "");
                 
        }
                
      }catch(Exception e){
                 System.out.println("exception was occureddddddddd"+e);
                
            }
        
    }
    public void onStart(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println(" 999999999999999999999999");
        Display();
    }
  }
```

---

Instead of giving any output in debugging mode in Eclipse
its giving the following in LogCat

```
07-07 23:13:52.340: INFO/installd(228): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.hi.address-1.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.hi.address-1.apk@classes.dex
07-07 23:13:52.340: DEBUG/PackageManager(284): New package installed in /data/app/com.hi.address-1.apk
07-07 23:13:52.470: WARN/PackageManager(284): Unable to load service info ResolveInfo{41789898 com.smlds.smlStartService p=0 o=0 m=0x108000}
07-07 23:13:52.470: WARN/PackageManager(284): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: No android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator meta-data
07-07 23:13:52.470: WARN/PackageManager(284):     at android.content.pm.RegisteredServicesCache.parseServiceInfo(RegisteredServicesCache.java:377)
07-07 23:13:52.470: WARN/PackageManager(284):     at android.content.pm.RegisteredServicesCache.generateServicesMap(RegisteredServicesCache.java:261)
07-07 23:13:52.470: WARN/PackageManager(284):     at android.content.pm.RegisteredServicesCache$1.onReceive(RegisteredServicesCache.java:110)
07-07 23:13:52.470: WARN/PackageManager(284):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:716)
07-07 23:13:52.470: WARN/PackageManager(284):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-07 23:13:52.470: WARN/PackageManager(284):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-07 23:13:52.470: WARN/PackageManager(284):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
07-07 23:13:52.470: WARN/PackageManager(284):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:682)
07-07 23:13:52.490: DEBUG/PackageManager(284): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 8 services unchanged
07-07 23:13:52.500: DEBUG/AccountTypeManager(422): Registering external account type=com.sec.android.app.snsaccountlinkedin.account_type, packageName=com.sec.android.app.snsaccountli
07-07 23:13:52.510: DEBUG/PackageManager(284): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 18 services unchanged
07-07 23:13:52.510: INFO/ApplicationPolicy(284): registerPackageChangeReceiver() onReceive: Broadcast Received for PKG:com.hi.address
07-07 23:13:52.520: INFO/DmAppInfo(284): getApplicationsList found row counts : 0 For Pkg : com.hi.address
07-07 23:13:52.520: DEBUG/szipinf(284): Initializing inflate state
07-07 23:13:52.520: DEBUG/GTalkService(399): [GTalkService.1] handlePackageInstalled: re-initialize providers
07-07 23:13:52.530: DEBUG/GTalkService(399): [RawStanzaProvidersMgr] ##### searchProvidersFromIntent
07-07 23:13:52.530: DEBUG/AccountTypeManager(422): Registering external account type=com.sec.android.app.snsaccountfacebook.account_type, packageName=com.sec.android.app.snsaccountfb
07-07 23:13:52.550: DEBUG/AccountTypeManager(422): Registering external account type=com.smlds.accountType, packageName=com.smlds
07-07 23:13:52.560: INFO/AccountTypeManager(422): Loaded meta-data for 6 account types, 2 accounts in 9ms
07-07 23:13:52.650: DEBUG/dalvikvm(422): GC_CONCURRENT freed 526K, 9% free 6904K/7559K, paused 2ms+3ms
07-07 23:13:52.690: DEBUG/dalvikvm(284): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1645K, 52% free 18542K/38151K, paused 7ms+10ms
07-07 23:13:52.700: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(5253): Shutting down VM
07-07 23:13:52.700: INFO/AndroidRuntime(5253): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
07-07 23:13:52.710: DEBUG/dalvikvm(5253): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 87% free 344K/2560K, paused 0ms+1ms
07-07 23:13:52.710: DEBUG/jdwp(5253): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
07-07 23:13:52.710: DEBUG/dalvikvm(5253): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
07-07 23:13:52.840: DEBUG/dalvikvm(362): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8092K, 43% free 13640K/23815K, paused 37ms
07-07 23:13:52.930: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(5269): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
07-07 23:13:52.930: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(5269): CheckJNI is OFF
07-07 23:13:52.930: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(5269): Set to default setting_5 : language=-Duser.language=en propLang=en
07-07 23:13:52.930: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5269): Set to default setting_6 : region=-Duser.region=US propRegn=US
07-07 23:13:52.940: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(5269): setted country_code = UK &amp; IRE
07-07 23:13:52.940: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(5269): setted sales_code = XEU
07-07 23:13:52.940: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(5269): found sales_code tag = <XEU>, </XEU> 
07-07 23:13:52.950: DEBUG/dalvikvm(362): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4042K, 53% free 11324K/23815K, paused 33ms
07-07 23:13:53.050: DEBUG/LibQmg_native(5269): register_android_app_LibQmg
07-07 23:13:53.080: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(5269): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
07-07 23:13:53.090: INFO/ActivityManager(284): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.hi.address/.HiActivity } from pid 5269
07-07 23:13:53.100: INFO/SurfaceFlinger(223): id=160(35) createSurface 0xa05bc for pid 284 (1x1),2 flag=0, Starting com.hi.address
07-07 23:13:53.100: DEBUG/WindowManager(284): addWindowToListInOrder() : current mSkipWidgetFocus='true'
07-07 23:13:53.110: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(5269): Shutting down VM
07-07 23:13:53.120: INFO/AndroidRuntime(5269): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
07-07 23:13:53.120: DEBUG/dalvikvm(5269): GC_CONCURRENT freed 103K, 86% free 374K/2560K, paused 0ms+1ms
07-07 23:13:53.130: DEBUG/dalvikvm(362): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1169K, 51% free 11766K/23815K, paused 3ms+11ms
07-07 23:13:53.140: DEBUG/jdwp(5269): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
07-07 23:13:53.140: DEBUG/dalvikvm(5269): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
07-07 23:13:53.260: DEBUG/dalvikvm(362): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1359K, 50% free 12140K/23815K, paused 2ms+3ms
07-07 23:13:53.350: DEBUG/dalvikvm(362): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1308K, 49% free 12273K/23815K, paused 29ms
07-07 23:13:53.480: DEBUG/dalvikvm(362): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1354K, 47% free 12839K/23815K, paused 2ms+3ms
07-07 23:13:53.610: WARN/ActivityManager(284): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{409bfaf0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
07-07 23:13:53.620: DEBUG/dalvikvm(362): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1603K, 45% free 13116K/23815K, paused 32ms
07-07 23:13:53.620: INFO/ActivityManager(284): Start proc com.hi.address for activity com.hi.address/.HiActivity: pid=5278 uid=10116 gids={}
07-07 23:13:53.700: INFO/System.out(5278): *********************************************************
07-07 23:13:53.700: DEBUG/WindowManager(284): addWindowToListInOrder() : current mSkipWidgetFocus='true'
07-07 23:13:53.710: VERBOSE/TLINE(5278): new: android.text.TextLine@4070ce08
07-07 23:13:53.710: INFO/SurfaceFlinger(223): id=161(1) createSurface 0x7f6dc for pid 5278 (1x1),2 flag=0, com.hi.address/com.hi.address.HiActivity
07-07 23:13:53.750: INFO/WindowManager(284): Putting input method here!
07-07 23:13:53.750: DEBUG/WindowManager(284):     w.mAttrs.token=ActivityRecord{4173b240 com.hi.address/.HiActivity}
07-07 23:13:53.750: DEBUG/WindowManager(284):     w.mToken=AppWindowToken{426016a0 token=ActivityRecord{4173b240 com.hi.address/.HiActivity}}
07-07 23:13:53.750: DEBUG/WindowManager(284):     token=AppWindowToken{426016a0 token=ActivityRecord{4173b240 com.hi.address/.HiActivity}}
07-07 23:13:53.750: INFO/WindowManager(284): Placing input method @3
07-07 23:13:53.750: DEBUG/CLIPBOARD(284): Hide Clipboard dialog inside hideSoftInput() !
07-07 23:13:53.750: INFO/InputManagerService(284): [imme] in windowGainedFocus()j, viewHasFocus is false OR is TextEditor is false, now call hideCurrentInputLocked(InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS,null)
07-07 23:13:53.790: DEBUG/dalvikvm(362): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1501K, 43% free 13660K/23815K, paused 3ms+5ms
07-07 23:13:53.840: DEBUG/CLIPBOARD(5278): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
07-07 23:13:53.870: WARN/SocialHubWidget(1064): [SocialHubWidgetProvider] onReceive() >>  
07-07 23:13:53.870: WARN/SocialHubWidget(1064): [SocialHubWidgetProvider] action >> action : sec.android.intent.action.HOME_PAUSE
07-07 23:13:53.870: WARN/SocialHubWidget(1064): [SocialHubWidgetProvider] action >> checkNetwork(context) : false
07-07 23:13:53.890: ERROR/com.samsung.app(1072): [MSC]>>> WeatherWidgetProvider.java:322 [0:0] onReceive()@@@ sec.android.intent.action.HOME_PAUSE
07-07 23:13:53.890: ERROR/com.samsung.app(1072): [MSC]>>> WidgetIdManager.java:39 [0:0] AccuWeatherClockWidgetID_Length
07-07 23:13:53.890: ERROR/com.samsung.app(1072): [MSC]>>> WidgetIdManager.java:40 [0:0] getPrefIDs() : length = 0
07-07 23:13:53.890: ERROR/com.samsung.app(1072): [MSC]>>> WeatherWidgetProvider.java:1554 [0:0] disable handler
07-07 23:13:53.900: ERROR/(1080): onReceive sec.android.intent.action.HOME_PAUSE
07-07 23:13:53.900: DEBUG/ProgramMonitor(4443): START onReceive()_intent : Intent { act=sec.android.intent.action.HOME_PAUSE flg=0x10 cmp=com.sec.android.widgetapp.programmonitorwidget/.ProgramMonitorProvider }
07-07 23:13:53.900: DEBUG/CLIPBOARD(362): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
07-07 23:13:53.910: INFO/PhotoAppWidgetProvider(1101): Gallery PhotoWidget PauseSlideShow 
07-07 23:13:53.910: INFO/ActivityManager(284): Displayed com.hi.address/.HiActivity: +300ms
07-07 23:13:53.920: INFO/SurfaceFlinger(223): id=157 Removed com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher idx=1 Map Size=4
07-07 23:13:53.920: WARN/Surface(362): Not initializing the shared buffer client because mSurface=0x0 stats=0
```

Where is the error in my code? I am tried to debug but was no able to find my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()` to get uniquely identifier of the device (IMEI on GSM, MEID for CDMA).

Also set `READ_PHONE_STATE` permissionin manifest

Comment: @ Sunil Thanks for the advice , but this would be pure android coding what i am trying to do is build an application using java .... that could run on any device not only android.... let's say if i run the code given above in try catch block in PC i could get my MAC address ..... now i want to get the mac addresses of all the devices that have a jvm/kvm in them ....

Comment: @ Sunil .... so if i am writing the same code in android/j2me devices i think it should work ... henceforth m thinking of making it run for any device i choose in order to get there mac address and start my tracing sequence ....

Answer (score 2):

/*getMAC() method returns the MAC Addrdess */

```
public  String getMAC() {
        WifiManager wifiMan = (WifiManager)AppUtils.mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInf = wifiMan.getConnectionInfo();
        String macadd=wifiInf.getMacAddress();
        System.out.println("MAC address info---- "+macadd);
        if(macadd==null){
            macadd="1A:DC:5C:8E:15:7B";
        }

        return macadd;
    }
```

Comment: hi but this is only for android ....but I am trying to make a code  generalized for every platform/device.... can't we improve this code as if i write the code given in try catch it works fine for a system ....

Comment: /*try this */ String command = "ipconfig /all";
       Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
 
       BufferedReader inn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

Comment: but this is what i am doing in the above code ....this is done for PC's ....m asking tht wht abt the mobile platforms ?

Comment: did U tried this above code for your mobile. I am using this only.